# JavaScript image displaying not working

Tags: javascript

I've got some JavaScript code embedded inside an HTML document. When I run it, it doesn't display the images. The code is attached below and any help is appreciated.

```js
var images = new Array ("red.JPG");

function getCurrentImageIndex() {
 return images.indexOf(document.getElementById("image").src);
}

function next() {
 nextImage = (getCurrentImageIndex() + 1) % images.length;
 document.getElementById("image").src = images[nextImage];
}


function prev() {
 nextImage = (getCurrentImageIndex() - 1 + images.length) % images.length;
 document.getElementById("image").src = images[nextImage];
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<script>
  
  //script here

</script>

<img id="image" />

<button onCLick="next()">press me</button> 

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get in the console?

Comment: Are you getting any js error  ?

Comment: I am getting no errors what so ever

Comment: Do you get the 'broken image' icon instead of your image?

Comment: Your code is working, only image path is wrong.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing your code working (using @JohannesJander image paths and jquery to wire up the click event): https://jsfiddle.net/y7aqz62s/

Comment: it still isn't working for me even after pressing the button and the broken image picture doesn't even appear

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with your code that you've not shown us.  Try starting a complete new site/project/etc and work up from there.   The code *as provided* has nothing wrong.  Perhaps the source code has a different `id` for the image?   Or you're not checking the browser console window for errors?  Or it's not called "click"?   The code *as provided* has nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if I use absolute image paths:

```js
var images = [
   "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png", 
   "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/06caf7997bde5d38c5aee0e051206614?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG"
];



function getCurrentImageIndex() {
 return images.indexOf(document.getElementById("image").src);
}

function next() {
 nextImage = (getCurrentImageIndex() + 1) % images.length;
 document.getElementById("image").src = images[nextImage];
}


function prev() {
 nextImage = (getCurrentImageIndex() - 1 + images.length) % images.length;
 document.getElementById("image").src = images[nextImage];
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<script>
  
  //script here

</script>

<img id="image" />

<button onCLick="next()">press me</button> 

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and  did not make a difference. thanks anyway

Comment: So, does the code snippet I provided work? If yes, where's the problem?

Comment: the snippet you provided doesn't work for some reason. it is still not displaying the images

Comment: Do you have **javascript disabled** in your browser?

Comment: This code snippet works here, as does the same code in a fiddle (see other comment)

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly created a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxdpWJ) with your code.
It seems to work.
The only thing I've changed is the url of the images.

```
var images = new Array ("http://cdn.digital.guide/2015/09/test.gif", "http://xiostorage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/test.png");
```

Since you're using relative urls for the images, make sure they are correct.
As it is now, the images should be in the same folder of the html file.